# Can't use the port other than port 80 and 8080 on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an instance Ubuntu 13 on EC2 of AWS

In that instance, in installed 2 applications on nginx with port 80 and 8080. I have also Tomcat running on port 8888.

I have penned theses port with AWS console -> Securit Group -> Inbound -> Custom TCP rule.

It worked well until last night for all port 80, 8080, 8888.

But this morning, i can't connect to the port 8888. I don't change any thing neither on my instace nor on console of AWS.  I verify that wget localhost:8888 work well

Have you an idea to resolve this problem ?

Thank you in advanced.

Tien,

Comment: what does `telent <EC2_ip_address> 8888` says ? Run this command from workstation where you trying to connect from.

Comment: Is your tomcat server bound to 127.0.0.1 or localhost?  It's probable that your tomcat server is not allowing external connection. Not sure why it was working before and not it's not working, sounds like there was some manual intervention for *it* to not be working.

Comment: I thinks it is the problem of EC2. Because when i change the port of Tomcat to 8080, nginx to 8888, Tomcat work, but nginx doesn't work. telnet IP:8888, telnet IP:80, telnet:8080 doesn't work, but ssh -i amazon.pem ubuntu@IP work well.